# What is the procedure to prove this result?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

**Question**: If $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\tan^3\frac{\phi}{2}$ and $\tan\phi=2\tan\alpha$, show that $\theta+\phi=2\alpha$.

**My problem**: I cannot understand how to proceed from the given data since the given data involves trigonometric functions while the required result involves angles. May be we have to equate same trigonometric functions and then the respective angles. **I would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me the logic and the thought process behind the proof and the approach to prove the result**. (I have not posted any attempt because honestly i do not know where to start and how to start)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just  need to use the tangent addition formula 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)}{1-\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
let $t=\tan(\frac{\phi}{2})$ so $\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})=t^3$ and the half angle formula gives $\tan(\phi)=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tan(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2})=\frac{\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})+\tan(\frac{\phi}{2})}{1-\tan(\frac{\theta}{2})\tan(\frac{\phi}{2})}=\frac{t^3+t}{1-t^4}=\frac{t}{1-t^2}=\frac{1}{2} \tan(\phi)= \tan(\alpha).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How did you understand that the tangent addition formula has to be used and that too for $\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $\frac{\phi}{2}$. I mean is there any particular logic on the basis of which you did this?

Comment: I did try $\tan(\theta+\phi)$ initially & found myself using the half angle formulea excesively. So I tried $\tan(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2})$ and this seems to workout nicely. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Note that $\tan \left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)=\tan \alpha$ doesn't necessarily imply $\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}=\alpha$, which is why we have the counterexample given by @MichaelRozenberg.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong! Try $\phi=\alpha=0$ and $\theta=2\pi$.

Comment: I checked my book again but the given part is exactly that. Maybe those values are excluded (but nothing about that is said in the question).

Comment: @MrAP I think your book make a mistake.

Comment: The first equation depends on tangents of half angles. This only determines the angles up to multiples of $2\pi$. So the result is more precisely $\theta+\phi=2\alpha {\pmod  {2\pi}}$.

Comment: @Somos Yes, of course!